# Find the number of users with negative total

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite, transactions

I am trying to figure out a SQL query or a Python Pandas code for the following solution.

There are n number of USER_ID with various transactions.
Every USER_ID has more than one transaction.
Example USER_ID

```
000e88bb-d302-4fdc-b757-2b1a2c33e7d6
001926be-3245-43fa-86dd-b40ee160b6f9
```

Every Transaction has a TYPE

```
TOPUP
Bank_Transaction
P2P
and a couple more
```

I want to write a query in which 
(TOPUP) - (total of every other type of transaction) and returns all the USER_ID where TOPUP < Total of all the transactions.

Finding all the users who have less topup and more spending.

I hope I am making myself clear?

Comment: So there are 3 fields: `user_id`, `transaction_type` and `amount`?

Comment: Yes there are three fields.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the topup amounts to be positive and other spendings negative, then we are simply looking for users with a negative balance.

```sql
select user_id
from transaction
group by user_id
having sum(case when transaction_type = 'TOPUP' then amount else -amount end) < 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following may produce the result that you want :-

```
WITH counter AS (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM transactions AS a 
    WHERE 
        coalesce((SELECT sum(amount) FROM transactions WHERE transaction_type = 'TOPUP' AND user_id = a.user_id),0.0) -
            coalesce((SELECT sum(amount) FROM transactions WHERE transaction_type <> 'TOPUP' AND user_id = a.user_id),0.0) 
            < 0      
    GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT count() FROM counter;
```

- this assumes that the table name is **transactions**.

If you consider the following data :-

```
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES 
    ('000e88bb-d302-4fdc-b757-2b1a2c33e7d6','TOPUP',25.00)
    ,('000e88bb-d302-4fdc-b757-2b1a2c33e7d6','P2P',125.00)
    ,('000e88bb-d302-4fdc-b757-2b1a2c33e7d6','BANK-TRANSACTION',75.00)
    ,('000e88bb-d302-4fdc-b757-2b1a2c33e7d6','TOPUP',25.00)
    ,('000e88bb-d302-4fdc-b757-2b1a2c33e7d6','BANK-TRANSACTION',75.00)
    ,('000e88bb-d302-4fdc-b757-2b1a2c33e7d6','TOPUP',25.00)
    ,('000e88bb-d302-4fdc-b757-2b1a2c33e7d6','TOPUP',25.00)
    ,('000e88bb-d302-4fdc-b757-2b1a2c33e7d6','BANK-TRANSACTION',75.00)
    ,('000e88bb-d302-4fdc-b757-2b1a2c33e7d6','TOPUP',25.00)
    ,('000e88bb-d302-4fdc-b757-2b1a2c33e7d6','BANK-TRANSACTION',75.00)
    ,('000e88bb-d302-4fdc-b757-2b1a2c33e7d6','BANK-TRANSACTION',75.00)
    ,('000e88bb-d302-4fdc-b757-2b1a2c33e7d6','BANK-TRANSACTION',75.00)


    ,('001926be-3245-43fa-86dd-b40ee160b6f9','TOPUP',10.00)
    ,('001926be-3245-43fa-86dd-b40ee160b6f9','TOPUP',10.00)
    ,('001926be-3245-43fa-86dd-b40ee160b6f9','TOPUP',10.00)
    ,('001926be-3245-43fa-86dd-b40ee160b6f9','TOPUP',10.00)
    ,('001926be-3245-43fa-86dd-b40ee160b6f9','TOPUP',10.00)


    ,('XX1926be-3245-43fa-86dd-b40ee160b6f9','P2P',50.00)
    ,('XX1926be-3245-43fa-86dd-b40ee160b6f9','P2P',50.00)
    ,('XX1926be-3245-43fa-86dd-b40ee160b6f9','P2P',50.00)
    ,('XX1926be-3245-43fa-86dd-b40ee160b6f9','P2P',50.00)
    ,('XX1926be-3245-43fa-86dd-b40ee160b6f9','P2P',50.00)
;
```

Then the result of the above is :-

[image]

- i.e. the first and third users have a negative account balance, whilst the 2nd has a positive balance (and is therefore excluded from the count).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mike this is really helpful!

Comment: @AkashWadhwani that's good. If you believe that the answer helped you then please tick it as answered.